# andEngine alertdialog error

Tags: java, android, andengine

```
error java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside 
thread that has not called Looper.prepare() =(
```

If I call `showDialog (id)` in `GameActivity` - works
But if I call `activity.showDialog` from another class - an error

```
@Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  switch (id) {
  case 1:
      Log.d("Dialog", "Dialog 1");
      AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         alert.setTitle("Help");
         alert.setMessage("Help");
         WebView wv = new WebView(this);
         wv.loadUrl("http:\\www.google.com");
         wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
         {
             @Override
             public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
             {
                 view.loadUrl(url);
                 return true;
             }
         });
         alert.setView(wv);

         AlertDialog ALERT = alert.create();
      return ALERT;
  default:
        return null;
  } 
}
```

I want to call a dialog with any other class

UPDATE:

```
 new code activiti.runOnUiUpdate()

 @Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  switch (id) {
  case 1: 
      this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {

      Log.d("Dialog", "Dialog 1");
      AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         alert.setTitle("Help");
         alert.setMessage("Help");
         WebView wv = new WebView(this);
         wv.loadUrl("http:\\www.google.com");
         wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
         {
             @Override
             public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
             {
                 view.loadUrl(url);
                 return true;
             }
         });
         alert.setView(wv);
         AlertDialog aALERT = alert.create();

        }
      });
      return ALERT;
  default:
        return null;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Make your dialog in the `activity.runOnUiThread(...)` method

Comment: error - The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new Runnable(){}) is undefined

Comment: The constructor WebView(new Runnable(){}) is undefined

Comment: Replace the `this` in your webview constructor with the activity context.

Comment: replaced, exact same error

Comment: update your code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your dialog in the update thread method, example

```
 activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
     @Override
        public void run() {
    //code for dialog creation goes here
    }

 });
```

update any internal references from `this` to the activities context `activity`
also you could just `dialog.show()` at the end of creating it and make it show up after its created. Hope I helped.